# how to change jquery range slider value

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 100000,
      values: [ 10000, 30000 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    jQuery( "#amount" ).val( jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + ' - ' + jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

Problem is that if I move with cursor it writes value with dollars: $15000 - $25000, is it possible to remove the dollar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
```

To:

```
jQuery( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
```

Within your `slide` function.